# How to find the value of an ODE system at a specific time

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, scipy

I am learning how to code on python and I am trying to figure out how I could find the sum of solutions from an ODE system at a specific time.

For example, this is from the SciPy Cookbook the example is called "Modelling a Zombie Apocalypse" https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Zombie_Apocalypse_ODEINT.html

Here is part of the code from the website:

```
# zombie apocalypse modeling
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
plt.ion()
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 8

P = 0      # birth rate
d = 0.0001  # natural death percent (per day)
B = 0.0095  # transmission percent  (per day)
G = 0.0001  # resurect percent (per day)
A = 0.0001  # destroy percent  (per day)

# solve the system dy/dt = f(y, t)
def f(y, t):
     Si = y[0]
     Zi = y[1]
     Ri = y[2]
     # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
     f0 = P - B*Si*Zi - d*Si
     f1 = B*Si*Zi + G*Ri - A*Si*Zi
     f2 = d*Si + A*Si*Zi - G*Ri
     return [f0, f1, f2]

# initial conditions
S0 = 500.              # initial population
Z0 = 0                 # initial zombie population
R0 = 0                 # initial death population
y0 = [S0, Z0, R0]     # initial condition vector
t  = np.linspace(0, 5., 1000)         # time grid

# solve the DEs
soln = odeint(f, y0, t)
S = soln[:, 0]
Z = soln[:, 1]
R = soln[:, 2]

# plot results
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, S, label='Living')
plt.plot(t, Z, label='Zombies')
plt.xlabel('Days from outbreak')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.title('Zombie Apocalypse - No Init. Dead Pop.; No New Births.')
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

From this model, suppose I wanted to find out how many zombies and people are alive at a time of 4 days (ie: the sum of the living population and the zombie population at the time of 4 days). Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do `S[4]` for living population and `Z[4]` for zombie population. `S` and `Z` are the approximation values for those variable after solving the ODE system at each time `t`.

Remember that values may not be `int` so solution may not make sense to the physical problem:

```
print(S[4])
499.99899899996575
print(Z[4])
1.036906736082604e-09
```

You may think of this that at day 4 there is one person becoming a zombie but hasn't turned completely yet.

Hope this helps